# The sieve formula choosen in Zhang's breakthrough work in Twin Prime conjecture

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, twin-primes, sieve-theory

In the breakthrough work of the proof of weak twin prime conjecture, Goldstone, Pintz and Yildirim as well as Zhang use the following modified Selberg sieve:

$v=\lambda^2$

where $\lambda(n)$takes the form

$\lambda(n) = \sum_{d\in S_I:d|P(n)} \mu(d)a_d$

and choose 
$a_d := g\left(\frac{\log d}{\log R}\right)$

where g is A smooth function

I just ask a question that why is $a_d$ choosen in this form, what is the motivation for that? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off posting this on Mathoverflow